# A workaround which lets you use `mk-build-deps` (and fakeroot) on the Windows Linux Subsystem on Windows 10

Tags: package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dependencies, development

## apt-get build-dep

`apt-get build-dep` is a useful tool.  It installs the "build dependencies" of the specified application.

For example:

`sudo apt-get build-dep firefox`

will install all the tools you need in order to compile Firefox.

## mk-build-deps

There used to be no easy way to undo an `apt-get build-dep` operation.

But nowadays, `mk-build-deps` comes to your rescue.  Instead of using `apt-get build-dep`, you use can use `mk-build-deps` to create a new package which depends on your favorite application's dependencies.

`mk-build-deps` is a Perl script which is included as part of the `devscripts` package.

You can then use `aptitude install` to install the new package, and `aptitude remove` to install it (along with its dependencies).

## Windows Linux Subsystem

The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is a compatibility layer which lets you use part (but not all) of certain Linux distributions on top of Windows 10.

## My question

I tried to run `mk-build-deps jpilot`. I was using Ubuntu 16.04.2, on the Windows Linux Subsystem, on Windows 10 version 1703 (OS build 15063.483).

I got this output:

```
fakeroot, while creating message channels: Function not implemented
This may be due to a lack of SYSV IPC support.
fakeroot: error while starting the `faked' daemon.
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
Error in the build process: exit status 1
```

What's the workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the System V IPC version of `fakeroot` doesn't work properly on this version of Windows.

The solution is to run the command:

`sudo update-alternatives --set fakeroot /usr/bin/fakeroot-tcp`

After you've run the command one time, `mk-build-deps` will work as expected, forever.

(My answer is based on a [post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13404177) by Hacker News user "danieldk".)